# NestJS swagger module not working properly with generic crud controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to create a generic crud controller that use a generic crud service in a NestJS application. It works properly but the swagger module doesn't generate the documentation about the REST services parameters correctly.

This is the service:

```
import { Model, Document } from "mongoose";

export abstract class CrudService<CrudModel extends Document, CreateDto, UpdateDto> {

    constructor(protected readonly model: Model<CrudModel>) {}

    async findAll(): Promise<CrudModel[]> {
        return this.model.find().exec();
    }

    async create(dto: CreateDto): Promise<CrudModel> {
        const createdDto = new this.model(dto);
        return createdDto.save();
    }

    async update(id: any, dto: UpdateDto): Promise<CrudModel> {
        return this.model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, dto, { new: true });
    }

    async delete(id: any): Promise<boolean> {
        const deleteResult = await this.model.deleteOne({ _id: id });
        return deleteResult.ok === 1 && deleteResult.deletedCount === 1;
    }

}
```

This is the controller:

```
import { Body, Delete, Get, Param, Post, Put } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { CrudService } from "./crud-service.abstract";

export abstract class CrudController<CrudModel extends Document, CreateDto, UpdateDto> {

    constructor(protected readonly service: CrudService<CrudModel, CreateDto, UpdateDto>) {}

    @Get()
    async findAll(): Promise<CrudModel[]> {
        return this.service.findAll();
    }

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() dto: CreateDto): Promise<CrudModel> {
        return this.service.create(dto);
    }
    
    @Put(':id')
    async update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() dto: UpdateDto): Promise<CrudModel> {
        return this.service.update(id, dto);
    }

    @Delete(':id')
    async delete(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return this.service.delete(id);
    }

}
```

I found this issue on Github repo: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/86

The last comment mentions a solution using mixins but I can't figure it out how to adapt it to my needs

Answer (score 5):

I eventually went to describing my own schema.

Here is the custom decorator (NestJs example)

```
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiOkResponse, getSchemaPath } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export const OpenApiPaginationResponse = (model: any) => {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiOkResponse({
      schema: {
        properties: {
          totalPages: {
            type: 'number'
          },
          currentPage: {
            type: 'number'
          },
          itemsPerPage: {
            type: 'number'
          },
          data: {
            type: 'array',
            items: { $ref: getSchemaPath(model) }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  );
};
```

And here is a example of how it is applied to a controller

```
@OpenApiPaginationResponse(DTOHere)
public async controllerMethod() {}
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Only works with a generic field that is an array.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently, I found the solution with Decorators in **Nestjs** because for native properties Swagger can't recognize our **Generic Type Class < T >**.

I will show you how I could implement my solution with a Parameterized Pagination Class.

1. Specify our Pagination Class

   ```
    export class PageDto<T> {
      @IsArray()
      readonly data: T[];

      @ApiProperty({ type: () => PageMetaDto })
      readonly meta: PageMetaDto;

       constructor(data: T[], meta: PageMetaDto) {
        this.data = data;
        this.meta = meta;
      }
   }
   ```

Our parametrized type is `data`.

2. Create our Decorator class, that will map our parametrized type `data`

   ```
    export const ApiOkResponsePaginated = <DataDto extends Type<unknown>>(
        dataDto: DataDto,
    ) =>
        applyDecorators(
        ApiExtraModels(PageDto, dataDto),
        ApiOkResponse({
            schema: {
            allOf: [
                { $ref: getSchemaPath(PageDto) },
                {
                properties: {
                    data: {
                    type: 'array',
                    items: { $ref: getSchemaPath(dataDto) },
                    },
                },
                },
            ],
            },
        }),
        );
   ```

In this decorator we used the definition of [SwaggerDocumentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) for specify what will be our class that Swagger will be mapped.

3. Add our Decorator `ApiOkResponsePaginated` class in our Controller.

   ```
    @Get('/invoices')
    @ApiOkResponsePaginated(LightningInvoice)
    async getAllInvoices(
    @Auth() token: string,
    @Query() pageOptionsDto: any,
    ): Promise<any> {
    return this.client.send('get_invoices', {
        token,
        pageOptionsDto,
    });
    }
   ```

And that's how you can visualize in Swagger the representation of `PageDto<LightningInvoice>` response.

[image]

I hope this answer help you in your code.

Comment: This only works for paginated responses.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to Jeroen's answer. While this works for paginated queries it doesn't work for non-paginated queries.

For

I'd like to add to Jeroen's answer. While this works for paginated queries it doesn't work for non-paginated queries.

For non-paginated queries you can use the following:

```
export const BaseOpenApiResponse = <TModel extends Type<unknown>>(
  model: TModel
) => {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiExtraModels(BaseApiResponseDto, model),
    ApiOkResponse({
      description: `The result of ${model.name}`,
      schema: {
        allOf: [
          { $ref: getSchemaPath(BaseApiResponseDto) },
          {
            properties: {
              data: {
                $ref: getSchemaPath(model),
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  );
};
```

Notice instead of the items key with the array key, we go straight to using `$ref`.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the proposed solutions and I would like to add a solution for non-paginated response and paginated response on the same decorator and also adding more information to the endpoint

```
import { Type, applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiExtraModels, ApiResponse, getSchemaPath } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { SingleResponse } from './base-response.response';
import { PaginatedBaseResponse } from './paginated-base-response.response';

export const BaseOpenApiResponse = <TModel extends Type<unknown>>(input: {
  tmodel: TModel | [TModel];
  description: string;
  httpCode: number;
}) => {
  let model: TModel;
  let properties = {};
  const { tmodel, description, httpCode } = input;

  if (Array.isArray(tmodel)) {
    model = tmodel[0];

    properties = {
      data: {
        type: 'array',
        items: {
          $ref: getSchemaPath(model),
        },
      },
    };
  } else {
    model = tmodel;

    properties = {
      data: {
        $ref: getSchemaPath(model),
      },
    };
  }

  return applyDecorators(
    ApiExtraModels(
      Array.isArray(tmodel) ? PaginatedBaseResponse : SingleResponse,
      model,
    ),
    ApiResponse({
      status: httpCode,
      description,
      schema: {
        allOf: [
          {
            $ref: getSchemaPath(
              Array.isArray(tmodel) ? PaginatedBaseResponse : SingleResponse,
            ),
          },
          {
            properties,
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  );
};
```

On the controller endpoint you could use it something like this for paginated responses

```
  @Get()
  @BaseOpenApiResponse({
    tmodel: [MyModel],
    description: 'get all',
    httpCode: HttpStatus.OK,
  })
  getAll(): PaginatedBaseResponse<MyModel> {
    return {
      meta: {...},
      data: {...},
    };
  }
```

And for non-paginated response will be

```
  @Post()
  @BaseOpenApiResponse({
    tmodel: MyModel,
    description: 'create something',
    httpCode: HttpStatus.CREATED,
  })
  create(): SingleResponse<MyModel> {
    return { data: { ... } };
  }
```