# Dynamically change @Body type on POST

Tags: nestjs

I created a class to be extended from my controllers, so in my POST by the moment I define the BODY parameter like this

```
@Body() create: any
```

But I'm using swagger, so I want to display the schema.
I tried this approach:

```
type dto = {
  one: OneDto
  two: TwoDto
}
```

and then

```
@Body() create: dto['one']
```

But it's no showing the schema anyway.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this not by changing dynamically the type, but creating a controller factory. I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71396211/13192384)
and modify it according my needs.

```js
export function CrudController<T, C, U, Q>(
  createDto: Type<C>,
  updateDto: Type<U>,
  queryDto: Type<Q>
): Type<ICrudController<T, C, U, Q>> {
  const createPipe = new AbstractValidationPipe(
    { /* whitelist: true, */ transform: true /* forbidNonWhitelisted: true */ },
    { body: createDto }
  );
  const updatePipe = new AbstractValidationPipe(
    { /* whitelist: true, */ transform: true },
    { body: updateDto }
  );
  const queryPipe = new AbstractValidationPipe(
    { /* whitelist: true, */ transform: true },
    { query: queryDto }
  );

  class CRUD<T, C, U, Q> implements ICrudController<T, C, U, Q> {
    constructor(protected readonly service: CrudService<T, C, U, Q>) {}
    // protected ;

    @Post()
    @UsePipes(createPipe)
    @ApiBody({ type: createDto })
    @ApiCreatedResponse({
      description: "Created succesfully.",
      type: CreatedDto,
    })
    @ApiBadRequestResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    @ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    @ApiConflictResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    create(
      @Body() body: C
    ) {
      return this.service.createAsync(body);
    }

    @Get()
    @UsePipes(queryPipe)
    @ApiOkResponse({ description: "Retrieved succesfully.", type: queryDto })
    @ApiBadRequestResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    @ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    read(): Promise<any> {
      return this.service.readAsync();
    }

    @Get(":id")
    @ApiOkResponse({ description: "Retrieved succesfully.", type: queryDto })
    @ApiBadRequestResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    @ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    readOne(
      @Param("id", ParseIntPipe) id: number
    ): Promise<Q> {
      return this.service.readAsync(null, { id: id });
    }

    @Patch(":id")
    @UsePipes(updatePipe)
    @ApiBody({ type: updateDto })
    @ApiBadRequestResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    @ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    update(
      @Param("id", ParseIntPipe) id: number,
      @Body() body: U
    ): any {
      return this.service.updateAsync(body, { id: id });
    }

    @Delete(":id")
    @ApiBadRequestResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    @ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: ResponseDto })
    delete(
      @Param("id", ParseIntPipe) id: number
    ): any {
      return this.service.deleteAsync(id);
    }
  }
  return CRUD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

types don't exists at runtime and AFIAK the `@nestjs/swagger` plugin rely on them at runtime. So you can't even use `@Body() create: InterfaceCreate`. You must have some concrete class

This might help you to out: [How to generate Generics DTO with nestjs/swagger](https://nartc.me/blog/nestjs-swagger-generics) (a post made by a guy that contributes a lot to `@nestjs/swagger` package)

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578329/nestjs-swagger-module-not-working-properly-with-generic-crud-controller
Supposedly solves the main problem, but at the end aren't displayed the schemas too.